# Combine two texts that share a PATTERN using bash code

Tags: bash, design-patterns

I have the two following text files:

First one:

```
chr10   1000    1001    DEL 2.4807  chr10   7443    8978
chr10   1005    1008    DEL 1.2799  chr10   7321    8778
```

Second one:

```
chr13  3456  6746  chr10 7443   8978
chr13  6453  8767  chr10 7321   8778
```

We can see they share a pattern:

```
chr10   7443    8978
chr10   7321    8778
```

So based on this pattern, how can I combine them into:

```
chr10   1000    1001    DEL 2.4807  chr10   7443    8978 chr13  3456  6746
chr10   1005    1008    DEL 1.2799  chr10   7321    8778 chr13  6453  8767
```

THanks

edit:
I've been trying grep like:

```
cat text1|grep -f `cat text2|awk '{print $4"\t"$5"\t"$6}'`
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail.  Bash itself might possibly be able to handle this, but it may be easier to use common tools that you can call from bash, like awk or perl.  Also, what's your tolerance?  I see the common  "last three fields" if you ignore whitespace.  Is that the pattern you want?  Last three fields?  Always and only three?

Comment: I think maybe some use of "grep". But still cannot figure out

Comment: to ghoti: yeah, the "three field" is pattern. I wanna combine the two texts based on such pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the three fields in an awk one-liner.  Here's a proof:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat file1
chr10   1000    1001    DEL 2.4807  chr10   7443    8978
chr10   1005    1008    DEL 1.2799  chr10   7321    8778
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat file2
chr13  3456  6746  chr10 7443   8978
chr13  6453  8767  chr10 7321   8778
[ghoti@pc ~]$ awk 'NR == FNR { what[$(NF-2),$(NF-1),$(NF)] = $0; next; } { printf("%s %s\n", what[$(NF-2),$(NF-1),$(NF)], $0); }' file1 file2
chr10   1000    1001    DEL 2.4807  chr10   7443    8978 chr13  3456  6746  chr10 7443   8978
chr10   1005    1008    DEL 1.2799  chr10   7321    8778 chr13  6453  8767  chr10 7321   8778
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

If you want the files in the other order, just change the order of `$0` and `what[]` in the printf().

Note that this assumes you're okay with loading the entire contents of the first file into an array in memory.  Probably shouldn't be used for files with millions of lines, but that'll depend entirely on the system you're running it on.

**How does this work?**

The awk script has two main sections, each in curly braces.  The first section ONLY runs if NR (the current record number of all data read so far) matches FNR (the record number in the current file).  In other words, it acts on only the first file.  The first file gets loaded into memory in an associative array whose subscript is the last three fields of the line.

The second section acts on every subsequent file after the first.  It simply prints the current line, but prepends it with the content of the array (matched in the first section) that matches the last three fields of the current line.

Comment: thanks a lot. it works. but can you explain a little bit about the "what" function in the script?

Comment: `what` is not a function, it's an array.  It's index consists of the three important values from file1 and values are the full lines.  For every item in file1, the index (last three fields) are assumed to exist in file2.

Comment: Just followup: I found that if there are several lines which share the same pattern(last three fields) in file1, the script will randomly pick up one. While I want all lines sharing the pattern...

Comment: It shouldn't be random; the script should record the LAST one, since the previous ones were overwritten in the array.  Try reversing the order of the files you list on the command line.  The FIRST file should have single entries for the last three columns.  The other files match against it.  If you want multi-to-multi relationships, then the script needs to be significantly more complex, and probably won't go on a single line anymore.